# Check if JS Object contains Array

Tags: javascript

I have a JS Object of attributes named `Attr` which may contain different arrays of attributes, such as `Color[]`, `Manufacturer[]`, `Brands[]` etc.

How can I check if the `Attr` contains a given property array?
For instance,   how can I check if `Attr` contains `Color[]`?

I tried this but it is not working:

```
if (Attr.hasOwnProperty('Color')) { 
    console.log("Has Colors array")
}
```

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: show how Attr is defined.

Comment: Attr is something that I get from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `attrs` itself is an array of objects, you're close in your solution, but you need to go down one more level.

To check if the first object in `attrs` (i.e., `attr[0]` . . . you could obviously loop through and use something like `attr[i]` as well) has a given array, you would be best using this approach:

```
if (attrs[0].hasOwnProperty("Color")) {
    . . . do something . . .
}
```

. . . or, even:

```
if (attrs[0].Color !== undefined) {
    . . . do something . . .
}
```

Either will work, both may be better suited for different situations (e.g., the first might be better if you are passing in the name of the array as a variable, the second if you are checking for a specific array name).

---

**Update:**

For the record, based on what is shown in your screenshot, the structure of you `attr` variable is:

```
attr = [
    {
        AspectRatio: [...],
        Binding: [...],
        Brand: [...],
        Color: [...],
        EAN: [...],
        EANList: [...]
    }
]
```

That should better show why you have to drop down one more level before you do your check.

Comment: undefined it is not a string.You must use `attrs[0].Color!=undefined`.

Comment: I guess it is working for... what is the issue Alexandru?

Comment: @user829174, please have a look here : https://jsfiddle.net/h5av96a2/1/

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai - yeah, typo . . . was thinking of the `typeOf` syntax as I was typing it.   :)   Fixed.

Comment: Which of your answer runs faster?

Comment: @user829174 - Excellent question.   :)    I've not yet checked.

Comment: @user829174 - just ran some quick checks locally and it seems like the two approaches are pretty close to even (they both process 10,000 iterations in a little over 0.9 seconds . . . 100,000 in about 9.5 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `Color` array exists and it's an `array`. Suppose that `Attr=attrs[0]`(according to your update).

```
if (Attr.Color!=undefined && Array.isArray(Attr)) { 
     console.log("Has Colors array");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `Array.isArray` function to check if the `Color` is an Array. Also as a gaurd condition, you can just check that if the Color property exists or not. From your updated post, it appears you can ignore that check.

```
 if (attrs[0].Color &&  Array.isArray(attrs[0].Color) ) { 

    console.log("Has Colors array")
}
```